# Search with split text in DB and get re-hitting value

Tags: php, sql, database, algorithm

I'd like to get the most matched data from DB by split array in search query.
Imagine my query is: **"How to buy a motorbike"** & in DB I've enlisted some data like

1. buy a helicopter
2. buy a motorbike
3. buy a car

So, after split the query, it'll search into DB as **"how"**, **"to"**,**"buy"**, **"motorbike"** respectfully. Using these sub-strings, the query only generate "**buy a helicopter**" string in output. But I want to get  **buy a motorbike** data. I generated a method but it only encode data when any of these sub-strings get matched with same data in DB.
Here's my code that fetch only first matched data but my desired data is in no. 2.

```
$str=$_POST['search']; 
$str=preg_split("/[\s]+/",  $str);
foreach ($str as $search ) {
$sql = "SELECT answer FROM query_tbl WHERE q1 like  '%".$search."%' ";
$record = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
$rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($record);
  if ($rows == true) {
     echo  json_encode(array('ans'=>$rows['answer']));
    } 
}
```

So, which algorithm should i follow and where to use it to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be best to do a full-text search as described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html).

> By default or with the IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE modifier, the MATCH() function performs a natural language search for a string against a text collection. A collection is a set of one or more columns included in a FULLTEXT index. The search string is given as the argument to AGAINST(). For each row in the table, MATCH() returns a relevance value; that is, a similarity measure between the search string and the text in that row in the columns named in the MATCH() list.